# fullPage.js On mobile chrome, trying to scroll up causes page reload

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

iOS mobile Chrome browser.

I have a multi section page using fullPage.js, works perfect in every situation except mobile Chrome browser due to Chrome's "pull down to reload page" feature.

If you try to scroll up (by sliding finger down) it will reload to the page. If you play with it some you'll find that sliding fast will allow you to scroll normally, but if you slide in a more natural way like someone used to scrolling on a website, it'll "stick" at first then just reload the page, instead of sliding up to the next page.

It causing an exceedingly poor user experience as any time the user tries to scroll up they see that little chrome menu bar with the reload/close/back buttons.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/imac/kemtmm9a/embedded/result/
Issue presents itself more clearly without the jsfiddle header but you can definitely see what's going on here.

**Update**

In testing this out with various solutions found online the root of the issue seems to stem from the fact that window.pageYOffset is always 0, regardless of where the user is on the page. This seems central to how fullPage.js operates which makes sense; however, Chrome detects for a scroll up when the window.pageYOffset=0 and enables the pull to refresh at that time. I am trying to work through some JS to use preventDetault when the user tries to scroll but it's either not working or causing fullPage.js to go haywire.

Comment: This is no real solution, but don't attempt to invent your own scroll behavior. It's nothing but annoying for users. If a designer asked me to do it because they've seen an awesome site that works perfectly on their perfect Apple product I'd say no, it will inevitably fail somewhere. With that said it does work on my Android Chrome. Quite well actually. But have you looked into scroll-snap-points?

Comment: @powerbuoy I must have not explained my issue well. I am using a 3rd party library fullPage.js for a series of full page feeling sections, which are all housed in a single html page. It manages the scrolling, snap to scroll, smooth scroll, etc... and works perfectly on all devices and all browsers. My specific issue is only with Chrome's mobile browser (both iOS and Android). Due to the nature of the library the window.pageYOffset is always equal to 0. When it's 0, and the user tries to scroll up, Chrome helpfully reloads the page. I want to stop that from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the library author's help (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2277) am now able to solve with his solution of setting `scrollBar:true and autoScrolling:true`

This causes the yOffset to behave normally and Chrome does not autorefresh